# If ui state provider redirect to particular template and in that I have to check authentication & need to redirect to dashboard

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If ui state provider redirect to particular template and in that I have to check authentication if its ng-switch-when=true need to redirect to dashboard

Below is my state provider configuration. and below is my mail.html.

on click on home page I need to check if the user logged in then redirect to dashboard.html template, Is it possible to do it in resolve method ?.

```
  angular.module('sample')
        .config(function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    parent: 'site',
                    url: '/',
                    data: {
                        roles: []
                    },
                    views: {
                        'content@': {
                            templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/main.html',
                            controller: 'MainController'
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: {

                    }
                });
        });



<div ng-cloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h3>Welcome to Admin portal!</h3>

            <div ng-switch="isAuthenticated()">
                <div class="alert alert-success" ng-switch-when="true">
                     You are logged In.
                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-switch-when="false">
                    If you want to <a href="#/login">Login</a>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Simple terms, Is it possible to have a "templateURL" definition for a particular view inside resolve method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can apply the same in resolve. Define the function isAuthenticated() in resolve and check you condition there and return true/false as you want.

```
angular.module('sample')
            .config(function ($stateProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                        parent: 'site',
                        url: '/',
                        data: {
                            roles: []
                        },
                        views: {
                            'content@': {
                                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/main/main.html',
                                controller: 'MainController'
                            }
                        },
                        resolve: {
                             isAuthenticated : function () {
                                //get your condiion here  for checking iff user is logged in    
                               if(logged in ) 
                                 return true
                               else 
                                 return false

                             }
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Comment: I dont want to return true / false, But I need to redirect to different template.

Comment: Hi Chauhan., You are right, but that "logged In" where do i get this from?

Comment: You can use angular service for the storing cookies "ngCookies" or store user info in browser localstorage on log in. This would help you in your complete app to check whether any one is logged in. and then check in the isAuthenticated() whether the cookies or localstorage is set means there is someone logged in